# why does code throw exception from an environnement iis to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

i deploy asp mvc web application in my local iis does work correctly, but when i moved to another iis start throwing exception not thrown before, i do not know whether there's nmatching in configuration.

```
  DateTime date_deb = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_deb, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
  DateTime date_fin = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_fin, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

> [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
>        System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>        DateTimeStyles style) +3200706
>        System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider) +31

//other exception here

```
IList<object[]> bilansMois = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List<object[]>();
 bilansMois[0].Count() != 0
```

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less 
>        than the size of the collection.
>        Parameter name: index]
>        System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +72
>         System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +9593284

Comment: this will be to do with the culture of the system i.e server 1 would be US and server 2 maybe UK culture. Remember, you should standardise your datetime construction in your app to avoid such problems

Comment: date problem solved still the second

Comment: i made that :         DateTime date_deb = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_deb, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);:             but still the problem with the IList

Comment: quite simple. you are not getting any data back so the collection has no items... but you re trying to reference an item that does not exist in the collection. ALWAYS check the object before accessing it to see if it has items before accessing the item. never think you will always have data

Comment: maybe that thanks a lot, i'll try thanks

Answer (score 0):

What locality is the server set to?,  it would seem you are passing the datetime in the wrong format for IIS to recognise

Comment: probleme with date resolved still the second problem